# Problemas com NullPointerException num projeto JSF

Tags: java, jpa, jsf-2.2, cdi

Estou com uma aplicação que está apresentando o seguinte mensagem de erro;

```
jun 01, 2015 4:15:05 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
ADVERTÊNCIA: #{pesquisaPedidosBean.pesquisar}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{pesquisaPedidosBean.pesquisar}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.algaworks.pedidovenda.controller.PesquisaPedidosBean.pesquisar(PesquisaPedidosBean.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:245)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 30 more
```

Segundo a mensagem de erro indica que o método pesquisar está dando NULL

que é esse método aqui

```
public void pesquisar() {
    pedidosFiltrados = pedidos.filtrados(filtro);
}
```

E essa é classe Bean

```
package com.algaworks.pedidovenda.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import com.algaworks.pedidovenda.model.Pedido;
import com.algaworks.pedidovenda.model.StatusPedido;
import com.algaworks.pedidovenda.repository.Pedidos;
import com.algaworks.pedidovenda.repository.filter.PedidoFilter;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class PesquisaPedidosBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private Pedidos pedidos;

    private PedidoFilter filtro;
    private List<Pedido> pedidosFiltrados;

    public PesquisaPedidosBean() {
        filtro = new PedidoFilter();
        pedidosFiltrados = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void pesquisar() {

        pedidosFiltrados = pedidos.filtrados(filtro);

    }

    public StatusPedido[] getStatuses() {
        return StatusPedido.values();
    }

    public List<Pedido> getPedidosFiltrados() {
        return pedidosFiltrados;
    }

    public PedidoFilter getFiltro() {
        return filtro;
    }

}
```

estou aberto a sugestões.

Comment: `pedidos` está nulo. Como você está habilitando `CDI` para o projeto?

Comment: Está assim https://github.com/wladyband/Pedido

Answer (score 2):

Encontrei o problema, era somente a questão da anotação que não estava no padrão CDI

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class PesquisaPedidosBean implements Serializable {
```